# List pods per namespace in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have several namespaces in my cluster and would like a log like:

```
NAMESPACE            NAME                                          PODS  
MY_NAMESPACE         my_ns6446f67599-25g7f                         10
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `--all-namespaces` flag to get pods.

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

From your output, it looks like you are trying to print the `replicaset`s as there is a PODs count column in the output.

```
kubectl get replicaset --all-namespaces
```

If you want to limit the resulting columns, we can use the `--0 custom-columns=` parameter as below.

```
$ kubectl get replicaset --all-namespaces -o custom-columns=NAMESPACE:.metadata.namespace,NAME:.metadata.name,PODS:.status.replicas     
NAMESPACE            NAME                                          PODS  
MY_NAMESPACE         my_ns6446f67599-25g7f                         10
```

Comment: @RamonMedeiros - Are you mentioning that `--all-namespaces` is not working in your env? Can you share the two commands that you are using now including their outputs.

Answer (score 12):

You can also try this one liner:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1 -n -r
```

Which will yield:

```
136 some-ns
133 kube-system
119 other-ns
```

Explaining a bit:

- `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` will list all pods with namespace in the first column.
- `awk { print $1 }` will "filter out" the first column which is the namespace
- `sort` will sort the name of namespaces alphabetically
- `uniq -c` will count how many times each namespace appeared and aggregate with a count as the first column (e.g. `136 some-ns` means that `some-ns` appeared 136 times).
- `sort -k1 -n -r` this one will sort from the namespace which appeared the most (i.e. had most pods) to the one that appeared the least. `-k1` means that I am using the first column to sort, `-n` I am using numeric comparison and `-r` and I am doing a reverse ordering.

Comment: Small improvement: adding `--no-headers` to the kubectl command will prevent `NAMESPACE` to appear in the list as a namespace. The final command would end up like this:
`kubectl get pods --no-headers --all-namespaces | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1 -n -r`

Still sadly this approach won't return empty namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

This solution combines the json output of `kubectl get pods` and `kubectl get namespaces` in order to also display the namespaces where no pods are deployed.

```
kubectl get pods -o json --all-namespaces | jq --argjson ns "$(kubectl get namespaces -o json)" '.items | group_by(.metadata.namespace) | map({namespace: .[].metadata.namespace, count: . | length}) | . += ($ns.items | map({namespace: .metadata.name, count: 0})) | unique_by(.namespace) | sort_by(.count)'
```

The solution provides an array of json objects sorted by number of pods in ascending order and can be easily extended to obtain the desired output.

The "magic" happens when we add the contents of the `$ns` variable -which contains the namespaces- to the end of the array with count=0. These entries will be discarded by `unique_by` if the namespace was already found before -which means it contains pods-.

**Note:** the solution relies on jq's `unique_by` function to discard the second appearance of an object with the same key value, which as for the [documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#unique,unique_by(path_exp)) it is not granted but it happens to be implemented in this way.

Answer (score 1):

`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --no-headers |  awk '{print $1}'  | uniq -c`
it give the number of pod with namespace